# How do i add a message at the top of a automatic forwarded email in gmail?

Tags: gmail

I know this isn't a question about coding but i want to add a message at the top of a automatic forwarded email but i can't seem to find any way to do it?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a gmail click the settings button on the top-right, and then click the forwarding and POP/IMAP tab. in the forwarding section click "add a forwarding address".

Enter the email address that you want to automatically forward the email sent to and then press proceed.

Comment: ive done that but i want it to include a message in the forwarded email.

Comment: e.g. someone emails saying "Test" then in the forwarded email it says "(Coustom Message) Test"

Comment: also i tried to fix some of your grammar in your answer.